# Is it possible to create Rule-Based Styling with $geometry intersecting a second layer?

Tags: qgis, style

I am trying to create a rule-based style based on geometries *from another layer*.

I have found an example that does exactly what I want, except that it uses a geometry from WKT:

```
intersects( $geometry, geomFromWKT( 'POLYGON' ) )
```

(from [here](http://www.3liz.com/blog/rldhont/index.php?post/2012/11/06/Spatial-operators-in-QGIS-expression))

What I want to do is exactly the same thing, but with the second geometry based on a different layer rather than WKT.  As an example, I want to theme roads in black if they intersect a polygon layer, and grey if they do not. Is this possible?

Comment: What is the different layer type?

Comment: The second layer is a polygon shapefile that has been added to the QGIS project.

Comment: I would like to know if the subject above "Is it possible to create Rule-Based Styling with $geometry intersecting a second layer? " is now possible in the new version of Qgis.
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is currently not possible to create cross-layer queries using field calculator or expressions.

See also [How to use the Intersects function in the Field Calculator of QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/77524/how-to-use-the-intersects-function-in-the-field-calculator-of-qgis)

Comment: Thanks underdark; at least I wasn't missing something! I figured perhaps it was not possible.

Answer (score 2):

In QGIS 2.18 there is a plugin available called [refFunctions](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/refFunctions/) and when using the query builder, they show up in the **Reference** portion.
[image: query/rule builder in qgis with refFunction geomintersects example]

So this should work as a rule: `geomintersects('polygon_layer','ogc_fid')`

And possibly in conjunction with the `geomdisjoint()` function:
[image: symbology example with refFunctions plugin]

The field column in the above example just uses the `ogc_fid` primary key/id column but can be any column... Says it also accepts the `$geometry` variable but I haven't got that to work yet!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. In the 'rule based' symbology, choose the rule to be:

```
intersects($geometry, geometry(get_feature('layer name', 'attribute field name', 'value')))
```

Let's say you want your layer to intersect with geometry A (called 'A' in the field 'Name') in a second layer, called 'Other geometries'.

Then you would use:

```
intersects($geometry, geometry(get_feature('Other geometries', 'Name', 'A')))
```