# Geometric functions in field calculator in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

I had a look in the manual of QGIS and I also browsed the Internet to find some useful information about the geometric functions of the field calculator.

I've found [How to use the Intersects function in the Field Calculator of QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/77524) but I'm still confused.

Does anyone have some practical examples to add?

I think all these functions could be very useful, but at the moment, their usability is quite difficult for a 'normal' user.

Comment: Could you add some specific examples of what kind of geometric functions you'd like to do, to a specific dataset? You may find that the operations you'd like to do aren't appropriate for individual fields and rows in a vector layer.

Comment: suppose that I want a new field for my point layer with 2 values: 1 (or true) if the layer is less then 100 meters away from another point else 0 (or false).

Comment: For that example, you could use the **Distance Matrix** or the **Distance to nearest hub** functions to calculate the distance between points and then add a new column in the field calculator with an expression such as: `CASE WHEN "Field_1" < 100 THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END`

Comment: Although you can find some examples/tutorials by browsing the internet, your best source is probably right here (GIS StackExchange) as all sorts of problems are discussed with using the Field Calculator.