# How to use the "geometry generator" to intersect geometries with an entire layer in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, geometry, intersection, style

In the "geometry generator" style in QGIS, it's possible to define an intersection for a specific geometry of an other layer like this:

```
intersection($geometry, geometry(get_feature( 'other_layer_name','attribute_name','attribute_value')))
```

Is it possible to do the same but on an entire layer, not only on one geometry?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

@DPSSpatial's response - use of a filter - will style **entire polygons** of which some part intersects with a single feature from another layer.

I gather you want to style only the **intersections**, in which case your use of `intersection()` in the geometry generator is correct, but you want to style intersections of *all* features from another layer, not just one as with `geometry(get_feature())`.

If you are sticking purely to the Expression String Builder I'm not sure if this is possible with QGIS 2 without using custom functions. (see e.g. [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/77524/how-to-use-the-intersects-function-in-the-field-calculator-of-qgis?noredirect=1&lq=1), [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/247007/styling-specific-layer-by-using-polygon-mask-in-qgis/247024#247024), [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/245824/geometry-generator-get-feature))

However, if you are willing to try out **QGIS 3**, there is a way...

---

Firstly, let me assume that:

- the **LEFT** is what you want as a *style*
- and the **RIGHT** is what you're getting with `get_feature()` - one feature at a time.

[image: Full intersection]   [image: Intersecting one feature at a time]

---

QGIS 3 introduces the new `collect` aggregate function, which treats all the features in a layer (either current or other specified) as one multigeometry.

Using the following code in the geometry generator, you can generate the areas in PINK below (`2collect_cond`)

```
intersection(collect($geometry),
             aggregate('target_layer','collect',$geometry,
                        intersects($geometry,geometry(@parent))))
```

[image: QGIS 3 Geometry Generator Intersection]

This intersects a collection of the source geometry, with a collection of the target geometry, only where it intersects with the source (sounds kooky but read on)

- **`collect()`** collects the geometry of the current, source layer.

  - NOTE 1: You **must** `collect()` the source geometry, or else it (a) won't work at all, or (b) shows `collect_cond` - only intersections where 1 source feature intersects 1 target feature (in this example, B/D/E)
- **`aggregate()`** lets you specify features from other layers. Within it, `collect` is the function that works with geometries.

  - First you specify the target layer.
  - Then the field to collect is of course `$geometry` (now of the *target* layer, since we are within `aggregate()`).
  - NOTE 2: you need to **filter** the results of `aggregate()` to include only target layer features that intersect with any feature from the source layer. Otherwise you end up with `collect_simp` - totally borky.
  - The filter is specified with `intersect($geometry,geometry(@parent))`.
  - Remember, $geometry here refers to the *target* layer, so to specify the *source* feature you need to write `@parent`, then get the geometry from it with `geometry()`.

---

Bonus: You could further refine the results by source and/or target layer attributes by modifying the `collect()` and/or `attribute()` filter parameters respectively.

```
intersection(collect($geometry, filter:="source_attribute"='VALUE'),
             aggregate('target_layer','collect',$geometry,
                        intersects($geometry,geometry(@parent))
                        AND "target_attribute"='VALUE'))
```

[image: Style by source or target layer attributes]

NOTE: If you try this out in the "Filter" field by swapping out `intersection()` for `intersects()`, it only works for target layer attributes, AFAICT.

Comment: Can I also add that this is a lot more intuitive in SQL with the Virtual Layer... but be warned, it doesn't work with all data sources. At least not temporary scratch layers.

Answer (score 3):

I just got this to work with the following:

First, set up a rule-based renderer.

Then for the rule filter, use:

```
intersects($geometry, geometry(get_feature('Board_Current', 'BOARD_DIST', '3')))
```

Where:

**$geometry** refers to the geometry of the point layer
**'Board_Current'** is the layer_name (variable) of the polygon layer
**'BOARD_DIST'** is the column in the polygon layer I want to filter on
**'3'** is the value in the BOARD_DIST column I want to intersect features in the points layer

Works great! Thanks for getting me started with the code - I think the key  might be the rule-based renderer, and pay attention to single and double quotes (I still get hung up on which is used where...)