# Speed up colouring of contour lines by creating new layer?

Tags: layers, geometry, intersection, select, contour

Related to my previous question: [Colouring contour lines differently when they are inside polygons of another layer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/373473/colouring-contour-lines-differently-when-they-are-inside-polygons-of-another-lay) I would like to create a new layer based upon the result of the geometry generator linestring/multilinestring expression:

```
intersection(collect($geometry),aggregate('NZ_Snow_Polygons__Topo__1_50k__72b39e76_c3e8_4878_a811_8e3dc5ade0d4','collect',$geometry,intersects($geometry,geometry(@parent))))
```

That as the expression for a linestring/multilinestring geometry generator works but is very very slow. Hence I want to use the result for a new static layer and render like the contour layer - or at least that is my goal.

I've tried "Vector Selection", "Select by expression" with the expectation I can save the selection as a layer, but the expression above runs for over 24 hrs at which point my patience is exhausted and I kill it.

What is the correct way to create a new layer that is the collection of contour lines sections where they intersect the snow polygons? i.e. Gives me the results I get with the geometry generator with none of the constant regeneration and slowness.

Comment: Have you tried to use `Geometry by expression` from the processing toolbox?

Comment: Naively tried "Geometry by expression" with the expression in the post. The result is that aggregate cannot be used. "Evaluation error: Cannot use aggregate function in this context
Execution failed after 0.05 seconds"

Comment: What GIS software are you using?

Comment: Hi PolyGeo, I'm using QGIS 3.14 - thanks.