# Changing line style while crossing specific multipolygon using QGIS

Tags: qgis, symbology, style, rule

I'm new to QGIS and trying to change river style while crossing a lake. Something like this with one line and multipolygon:

[image: line crossing a multipolygon]

Currently, I have two styles on one line:

[image]

[image]

It is one single line with "waterway"='stream' tag and one polygon with "natural"='water' tag. Have data from OSM file.

Is it possible to check if the line crosses a polygon and automatically changes the style?

I want to apply this rule to all lines with "waterway"='stream' tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on this awesome [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/190688/how-to-use-the-geometry-generator-to-intersect-geometries-with-an-entire-layer) something like this should work:

1. Create a `Geometry Generator` with type `LineString` where you want to get the `difference` of your current `geometry` and the aggregated geometry of your polygon layer (only for elements that intersect with lines - see other answer for a very good explanation). This will give you the lines without the parts where they overlap the water polygons

```
difference(
    collect($geometry), 
    aggregate(
        'waterway_polygons',
        'collect',
        $geometry,
        intersects(
            $geometry,
            geometry(@parent)
        )
    )
)
```

2. Then you create a second `Geometry Generator` where you do the same but this time we are not calculating the `difference` but the `intersection` with the polygons, which will give you all the parts where you want to display only markers. Here you can use a `Marker Line` for styling.

```
intersection(
    collect($geometry), 
    aggregate(
        'waterway_polygons',
        'collect',
        $geometry,
        intersects(
            $geometry,
            geometry(@parent)
        )
    )
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, it works nice. I finally understand the rules and the geometry generator. I forgot to mention that I use QuickOSM to download all data into lines and polygons layers. Wrote this:
`intersection(aggregate('lines', 'collect', $geometry, "waterway"='stream'), aggregate('polygons', 'collect', $geometry, "natural"='water'))`

Answer (score 0):

I use QuickOSM plugin to download all data with the Canvas Extent setting:

[image]

After it is finished I rename the polygon layer to polygons and the line layer to lines:

[image]

Then set lines layer symbology to rule-based and created one rule ("waterway"='stream'):

[image]

For the polygons layer I set another rule ("natural"='water'):

[image]

Then create two geometry generators under the "waterway"='stream' rule:

[image]

For the first geometry generator (blue arrows) I use this code:

```
intersection(
     aggregate('lines', 'collect',$geometry, "waterway"='stream'),
     aggregate(
         'polygons',
         'collect',
         $geometry,
         "natural"='water'
     )
)
```

And for the second geometry generator (blue line) I use this:

```
difference(
     aggregate('lines', 'collect',$geometry, "waterway"='stream'),
     aggregate(
         'polygons',
         'collect',
         $geometry,
         "natural"='water'
     )
)
```

And it works:
[image]